# Calculating Bayes Factor from Z score, n, and No

Tags: r, bayesian, bayes-factors

I'm completely stuck on how to get this answer from a course below.

[image]

I guessed the answer, but I'm lost on how they get to it. I did the following in R

```
N_0 = 1
n = 1000
z = 2.055
BF = (((n+N_0)/n)^0.5)* exp((-1/2)*(n/(n+N_0)*z^2))
BF
[1] 0.121371
```

Given the Bayes Factor is 3.83, I know I've screwed up somewhere (and got the right answer by accident.

Can anyone help spot my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in the way you are calculating the BF.
The BF should be 
BF = (((n+N_0)/N_0)^0.5)* exp((-1/2)*(n/(n+N_0)*z^2)) 
based on the formula provided in the text.
You have used,
BF = (((n+N_0)/n)^0.5)* exp((-1/2)*(n/(n+N_0)*z^2))

Comment: Wow...I can't believe it was something that darn simple. Thank you!